# HEVC encoder with 10 Bit

Tags: encode, hevc

Hi I'm trying to encode Images with the HEVC Encoder HM 16.8. As soon as I change the InputBitDepth in the cfg- File to 10 Bits i get the following output:

> SUMMARY --------------------------------------------------------
>     Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR 
>             0    a         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
>
> I Slices--------------------------------------------------------
>     Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR 
>             0    i         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
>
> P Slices--------------------------------------------------------
>     Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR 
>             0    p         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
>
> B Slices--------------------------------------------------------
>     Total Frames |   Bitrate     Y-PSNR    U-PSNR    V-PSNR    YUV-PSNR 
>             0    b         -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan      -nan
>
> RVM: 0.000 Bytes written to file: 0 (-nan kbps)

Input- Image:
RAW-YUV 10Bit 3840x2160 25fps

Input-command:
./TAppEncoderstatic -c test_422_10_rext -f 1 -fr 25 -wdt 3840 -hgt 2160 -i Input.yuv

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I used the attached cfg- File.

```js
#======== File I/O =====================
BitstreamFile                 : str.bin
ReconFile                     : rec.yuv

InputBitDepth        : 10
OutputBitDepth        : 10
InputChromaFormat       : 422

#======== Profile definition ==============
Profile                       : main-RExt   # Profile name to use for encoding. Use main (for FDIS main), main10 (for FDIS main10), main-still-picture, main-RExt, high-throughput-RExt, main-SCC
Tier                          : main        # Tier to use for interpretation of --Level (main or high only)"
Level         : 5.1

#======== Unit definition ================
MaxCUWidth                    : 64          # Maximum coding unit width in pixel
MaxCUHeight                   : 64          # Maximum coding unit height in pixel
MaxPartitionDepth             : 4           # Maximum coding unit depth
QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize         : 5           # Log2 of maximum transform size for
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...6)
QuadtreeTULog2MinSize         : 2           # Log2 of minimum transform size for
                                            # quadtree-based TU coding (2...6)
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthInter       : 3
QuadtreeTUMaxDepthIntra       : 3

#======== Coding Structure =============
IntraPeriod                   : 1           # Period of I-Frame ( -1 = only first)
DecodingRefreshType           : 0           # Random Accesss 0:none, 1:CRA, 2:IDR, 3:Recovery Point SEI
GOPSize                       : 1           # GOP Size (number of B slice = GOPSize-1)
#        Type POC QPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2  temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures  

#=========== Motion Search =============
FastSearch                    : 1           # 0:Full search  1:TZ search
SearchRange                   : 64          # (0: Search range is a Full frame)
HadamardME                    : 1           # Use of hadamard measure for fractional ME
FEN                           : 1           # Fast encoder decision
FDM                           : 1           # Fast Decision for Merge RD cost

#======== Quantization =============
QP                            : 32          # Quantization parameter(0-51)
MaxDeltaQP                    : 0           # CU-based multi-QP optimization
MaxCuDQPDepth                 : 0           # Max depth of a minimum CuDQP for sub-LCU-level delta QP
DeltaQpRD                     : 0           # Slice-based multi-QP optimization
RDOQ                          : 1           # RDOQ
RDOQTS                        : 1           # RDOQ for transform skip

#=========== Deblock Filter ============
LoopFilterOffsetInPPS         : 1           # Dbl params: 0=varying params in SliceHeader, param = base_param + GOP_offset_param; 1 (default) =constant params in PPS, param = base_param)
LoopFilterDisable             : 0           # Disable deblocking filter (0=Filter, 1=No Filter)
LoopFilterBetaOffset_div2     : 0           # base_param: -6 ~ 6
LoopFilterTcOffset_div2       : 0           # base_param: -6 ~ 6
DeblockingFilterMetric        : 0           # blockiness metric (automatically configures deblocking parameters in bitstream). Applies slice-level loop filter offsets (LoopFilterOffsetInPPS and LoopFilterDisable must be 0)

#=========== Misc. ============
InternalBitDepth              : 10          # codec operating bit-depth

#=========== Coding Tools =================
SAO                           : 1           # Sample adaptive offset  (0: OFF, 1: ON)
AMP                           : 1           # Asymmetric motion partitions (0: OFF, 1: ON)
TransformSkip                 : 1           # Transform skipping (0: OFF, 1: ON)
TransformSkipFast             : 1           # Fast Transform skipping (0: OFF, 1: ON)
SAOLcuBoundary                : 0           # SAOLcuBoundary using non-deblocked pixels (0: OFF, 1: ON)

#============ Slices ================
SliceMode                : 0                # 0: Disable all slice options.
                                            # 1: Enforce maximum number of LCU in an slice,
                                            # 2: Enforce maximum number of bytes in an 'slice'
                                            # 3: Enforce maximum number of tiles in a slice
SliceArgument            : 1500             # Argument for 'SliceMode'.
                                            # If SliceMode==1 it represents max. SliceGranularity-sized blocks per slice.
                                            # If SliceMode==2 it represents max. bytes per slice.
                                            # If SliceMode==3 it represents max. tiles per slice.

LFCrossSliceBoundaryFlag : 1                # In-loop filtering, including ALF and DB, is across or not across slice boundary.
                                            # 0:not across, 1: across

#============ PCM ================
PCMEnabledFlag                      : 0                # 0: No PCM mode
PCMLog2MaxSize                      : 5                # Log2 of maximum PCM block size.
PCMLog2MinSize                      : 3                # Log2 of minimum PCM block size.
PCMInputBitDepthFlag                : 1                # 0: PCM bit-depth is internal bit-depth. 1: PCM bit-depth is input bit-depth.
PCMFilterDisableFlag                : 0                # 0: Enable loop filtering on I_PCM samples. 1: Disable loop filtering on I_PCM samples.

#============ Tiles ================
TileUniformSpacing                  : 0                # 0: the column boundaries are indicated by TileColumnWidth array, the row boundaries are indicated by TileRowHeight array
                                                       # 1: the column and row boundaries are distributed uniformly
NumTileColumnsMinus1                : 0                # Number of tile columns in a picture minus 1
TileColumnWidthArray                : 2 3              # Array containing tile column width values in units of CTU (from left to right in picture)   
NumTileRowsMinus1                   : 0                # Number of tile rows in a picture minus 1
TileRowHeightArray                  : 2                # Array containing tile row height values in units of CTU (from top to bottom in picture)

LFCrossTileBoundaryFlag             : 1                # In-loop filtering is across or not across tile boundary.
                                                       # 0:not across, 1: across 

#============ WaveFront ================
WaveFrontSynchro                    : 0                # 0:  No WaveFront synchronisation (WaveFrontSubstreams must be 1 in this case).
                                                       # >0: WaveFront synchronises with the LCU above and to the right by this many LCUs.

#=========== Quantization Matrix =================
ScalingList                   : 0                      # ScalingList 0 : off, 1 : default, 2 : file read
ScalingListFile               : scaling_list.txt       # Scaling List file name. If file is not exist, use Default Matrix.

#============ Lossless ================
TransquantBypassEnableFlag : 0                         # Value of PPS flag.
CUTransquantBypassFlagForce: 0                         # Force transquant bypass mode, when transquant_bypass_enable_flag is enabled

#=========== RExt ============
ExtendedPrecision                   : 0               # Increased internal accuracies to support high bit depths (not valid in V1 profiles)
TransformSkipLog2MaxSize            : 2                # Specify transform-skip maximum size. Minimum 2. (not valid in V1 profiles)
ImplicitResidualDPCM                : 1                # Enable implicitly signalled residual DPCM for intra (also known as sample-adaptive intra predict) (not valid in V1 profiles)
ExplicitResidualDPCM                : 1                # Enable explicitly signalled residual DPCM for inter (not valid in V1 profiles)
ResidualRotation                    : 1                # Enable rotation of transform-skipped and transquant-bypassed TUs through 180 degrees prior to entropy coding (not valid in V1 profiles)
SingleSignificanceMapContext        : 1                # Enable, for transform-skipped and transquant-bypassed TUs, the selection of a single significance map context variable for all coefficients (not valid in V1 profiles)
IntraReferenceSmoothing             : 1                # 0: Disable use of intra reference smoothing (not valid in V1 profiles). 1: Enable use of intra reference smoothing (same as V1) 
GolombRiceParameterAdaptation       : 1                # Enable the partial retention of the Golomb-Rice parameter value from one coefficient group to the next
HighPrecisionPredictionWeighting    : 1                # Use high precision option for weighted prediction (not valid in V1 profiles)
CrossComponentPrediction            : 1                # Enable the use of cross-component prediction (not valid in V1 profiles)

### DO NOT ADD ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ###
### DO NOT DELETE THE EMPTY LINE BELOW ###
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean you are trying to encode a raw video right?
if you are trying to encode in main-ext you may need to enable Ext__HIGH_BIT_DEPTH_SUPPORT inside typedef.h

Comment: Hi i've enabled it, but it doesn't change anything. In the manuals it says that you only need to enable the rext_high_bit_depth_support when you use a 12 to 16 bit bitdepth.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't you use main10 as the profile rather than main-rext?

Comment: I've used main10 either, but I get the same Problem. It's the same with all possible cfg- Files

Comment: Can you be more specific about the content you are trying to encode?
Is it in raw yuv format? Also can you provide the command line arguments you are feeding to the encoder?

Comment: I really forgot half of the information..I'wrote them in the Question!